# jQuery Single Attribute, Multiple Values Selector with filter

Tags: jquery, selector

```
//Images
var boxlinks = $('a[href]').filter('[href$=".png"], [href$=".gif"], [href$=".jpg"], [href$=".jpeg"]');
```

Is there a more efficient way to select multiple values of a single attribute with a filter in jQuery, here I am trying to select links only with an image as an href.

Comment: `filter()` can accept a method as its input.  So in theory you could make a regex check against the href to see if it ends in any of the extensions.  Or if possible, you could throw an 'image' class on all of them and call it a day.

Comment: Can't do the class - was thinking regex also looking for a way to implement that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that uses a regex and a class.  The regex lowercases the href so it's insensitive.

```js
var boxlinks = $('a[href]').filter(function(){
      // regex checks for a literal period, followed by one of the extensions, and then
      // the end of the line
  return /[.](png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/.test(this.href.toLowerCase());
});

console.log(boxlinks.get());
console.log($('a.image').get());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/something/something/thing.txt"></a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/something/something/thing.png" class="image"></a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/something/something/thing.gif" class="image"></a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/something/something/thing.jpg" class="image"></a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/something/something/thing.jpeg" class="image"></a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/something/something/thing.PNG" class="image"></a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/something/something/thing.GIF" class="image"></a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/something/something/thing.JPG" class="image"></a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/something/something/thing.JPEG" class="image"></a>
```

Comment: Very nice, also didn't think of the case conversion, thanks