# Filter elements by search values - multiple words

Tags: jquery, filter

I have a list made of DIV's and an INPUT search box:

```html
<input id="search" type="text">

<div>Caramel Apples</div>
<div>Strawberry Lemonade</div>
<div>Pineapple Cake</div>
<div>Apple Pie</div>
<div>Cherry Ice Cream</div>
```

While typing in the search box, I want to do a live update to show only those rows that match ALL the search keywords, even if they are partials. If I type "app ca", I should get "Caramel Apples" and "Pineapple Cake".

I have not been able to make the standard jQuery [Attribute Contains Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) `[name*="value"]` work for more than one "value". [Multiple Attribute Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) doesn't seem to work either, probably because I am operating on just one attribute, not multiple.

As an added bonus, I also need it to be case-insensitive.

I found a similar question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101319/jquery-single-attribute-multiple-values-selector-with-filter), but it only does an OR filter on the keywords, not an AND. Nor is it dynamic, e.g. keywords being typed in. It may be a good start, but I don't know how to modify it to apply to my situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Trim the input value and split by multiple spaces to get an Array
- Compare the search Array with each element text string (both as lowercase) using [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) in combination with [Array.prototype.**some**()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) - or [Array.prototype.**every**()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) if you need that kind of search.
- Use a Utility class like `u-none {display: none}`
- Toggle that utility class using [Element.classList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) or jQuery's [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) Method

## Filter items by multiple search words

For multiple words, you'll have to split by space and treat each part as a valid search query:

```js
const EL_input = document.querySelector("#search");
const ELS_items = document.querySelectorAll("div");

const filterItems = (text) => {
  const words = text.trim().toLowerCase().split(/ +/);
  console.log(words);
  ELS_items.forEach(EL => {
    const cont = EL.textContent.trim().toLowerCase();
    const hasWord = words.some((w) => cont.includes(w));
    EL.classList.toggle("u-none", !hasWord);
  });
}

EL_input.addEventListener("input", () => {
  filterItems(EL_input.value);
});
```

```css
/* Utility classes */

.u-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id=search type=text autocomplete=off>

<div>Caramel Apples</div>
<div>Strawberry Lemonade</div>
<div>Pineapple Cake</div>
<div>Apple Pie</div>
<div>Cherry Ice Cream</div>
```

## Filter items by single search word

- Compare the search string with each element text string (both as lowercase) using [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
const EL_input = document.querySelector("#search");
const ELS_items = document.querySelectorAll("div");
// BE MORE SPECIFIC WITH YOUR SELECTORS! Use a class instead of "div"

const filterItems = (text) => {
  text = text.trim().toLowerCase();
  ELS_items.forEach(EL => {
    const cont = EL.textContent.trim().toLowerCase();
    const hasText = cont.includes(text);
    EL.classList.toggle("u-none", !hasText);
  });
}

EL_input.addEventListener("input", () => {
  filterItems(EL_input.value);
});
```

```css
/* Utility classes */

.u-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" autocomplete=off>

<div>Caramel Apples</div>
<div>Strawberry Lemonade</div>
<div>Pineapple Cake</div>
<div>Apple Pie</div>
<div>Cherry Ice Cream</div>
```

---

**Using jQuery** is quite similar, with the only difference of loading a [relatively big](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js) library unnecessarily (at this date (2021.)), but the code is quite the same:

#### jQuery - Filter items by multiple search words

```js
const $input = $("#search");
const $items = $("div");
// BE MORE SPECIFIC WITH YOUR SELECTORS! Use a class instead of "div"

function filterItems(text) {
  const words = text.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/ +/g, " ").split(" ");
  $items.each(function() {
    const cont = $.trim($(this).text().toLowerCase());
    const hasText = words.some((w) => cont.includes(w));
    $(this).toggleClass("u-none", !hasText);
  });
}

$input.on("input", function() {
  filterItems($(this).val());
});
```

```css
/* Utility classes */

.u-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" autocomplete=off>

<div>Caramel Apples</div>
<div>Strawberry Lemonade</div>
<div>Pineapple Cake</div>
<div>Apple Pie</div>
<div>Cherry Ice Cream</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### jQuery - Filter items by single search word

```js
const $input = $("#search");
const $items = $("div");
// BE MORE SPECIFIC WITH YOUR SELECTORS! Use a class instead of "div"

function filterItems(text) {
  text = text.trim().toLowerCase();
  $items.each(function() {
    const cont = $.trim($(this).text().toLowerCase());
    const hasText = cont.includes(text);
    $(this).toggleClass("u-none", !hasText);
  });
}

$input.on("input", function() {
  filterItems($(this).val());
});
```

```css
/* Utility classes */

.u-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" autocomplete=off>

<div>Caramel Apples</div>
<div>Strawberry Lemonade</div>
<div>Pineapple Cake</div>
<div>Apple Pie</div>
<div>Cherry Ice Cream</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I am primarily interested in a jQuery solution, so I tried your "jQuery - filter items by multiple search words" snippet. Unfortunately, it doesn't work entirely as I required in the original question. It is still an OR logic and not AND. If I enter "app ch", I get all the "apples" as well as "cherry". I should not get any results since "app" AND "ch" don't appear together in any of them.

Comment: @jfriend Use .every instead of .some

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<input id="search" type="text">

<div>Caramel Apples</div>
<div>Strawberry Lemonade</div>
<div>Pineapple Cake</div>
<div>Apple Pie</div>
<div>Cherry Ice Cream</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("div").css("display", function() {
            return this.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1 ? "":"none"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This does not work as expected. Typing "app" filters to all "apple" items, but just hitting space immediately removes all results.